# Why do I get InternalError: too much recursion with my NextJS Component?

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, next.js

I have a NextJS App that uses Firebase Realtime Database to fetch data. However, I get an **InternalError: too much recursion** everytime I use the production version of the page. I get no error on the local development server.

Code -
index.js

```
import { ref, getDatabase, get, child, set } from "firebase/database";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { app } from "../lib/firebase";
import Subject from "../components/Subject";
export default function Student() {
  const dbref = ref(getDatabase(app));
  const timetable = {
    Monday: ["DAA"],
    Tuesday: ["COMP", "ALC"],
    Wednesday: ["BEE", "OS"],
    Thursday: ["OE", "IT", "DM"],
    Friday: ["DBMS", "S&S"],
  };
  const days = [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday",
  ];
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [date, setDate] = useState(
    new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-GB").replaceAll("/", "-")
  );
  const [day, setDay] = useState(days[new Date().getDay()]);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Data Fetched!");
    get(child(dbref, "data/"))
      .then((snapshot) => snapshot.val())
      .then((d) => {
        if (d) setData(d);
      })
      .catch((e) => console.error(e));
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Data Updated!");
    set(child(dbref, "data/"), data).catch((e) => console.error(e));
  }, [data]);
  return (
    <main className="">
      <h1 className="text-4xl">Student View : </h1>
      <p>Selected Date : {date}</p>
      <p>Day : {day}</p>
      <p>Selected Day&apos;s subjects : {timetable[day].join(", ")}</p>
      <h3>Set Date :</h3>
      <input
        type={"date"}
        id="date"
        name="date"
        onChange={(e) => {
          if (e.target.valueAsDate !== null) {
            setDate(
              e.target.valueAsDate
                .toLocaleDateString("en-GB")
                .replaceAll("/", "-")
            );
            setDay(days[e.target.valueAsDate.getDay()]);
          }
        }}
      />
      {timetable[day].map((e) => (
        <Subject key={e} name={e} data={data} setData={setData} date={date} />
      ))}
    </main>
  );
}
```

Subject.jsx

```
export default function name({ name, data, setData, date }) {
  function todayTaken() {
    setData((old) => ({
      ...old,
      [date]: { ...old[date], [name]: 1 },
    }));
  }
  function notTaken() {
    setData((old) => ({
      ...old,
      [date]: { ...old[date], [name]: 0 },
    }));
  }
  function Cancelled() {
    setData((old) => ({
      ...old,
      [date]: { ...old[date], [name]: -1 },
    }));
  }
  return (
    <div className="border-2 p-4">
      <h2>Subject : {name}</h2>
      <div className="flex flex-row gap-4">
        <button
          className="bg-blue-500 py-2.5 px-4 text-white rounded-md"
          onClick={todayTaken}
        >
          Class Taken Today
        </button>
        <button
          className="bg-red-500 py-2.5 px-4 text-white rounded-md"
          onClick={notTaken}
        >
          Not Taken Today
        </button>
        <button
          className="bg-indigo-500 py-2.5 px-4 text-white rounded-md"
          onClick={Cancelled}
        >
          Cancelled
        </button>
        <h2>
          Today&apos;s status :{" "}
          {data[date]===undefined || data[date][name] === undefined
            ? "Not set"
            : data[date][name] === 1
            ? "Class Taken"
            : data[date][name] === 0
            ? "Class Not Taken"
            : data[date][name] === -1
            ? "Class Cancelled"
            : ""}
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm not sure as to what is going wrong, can someone show me what I'm doing incorrectly?
The first useEffect fetches data from Firebase when component mounts, and then when the data is changed then the data is **set** on Firebase which means that it does not trigger a rerender. I'm not sure what is going wrong here. The console doesn't provide any useful information.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating an infinite loop with these two effects:

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Data Fetched!");
  get(child(dbref, "data/"))
    .then((snapshot) => snapshot.val())
    .then((d) => {
      if (d) setData(d);
    })
    .catch((e) => console.error(e));
}, []);
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Data Updated!");
  set(child(dbref, "data/"), data).catch((e) => console.error(e));
}, [data]);
```

1. The first effect reads `/data` from the database and sets it to the state by calling `setData`.
2. The second effect responds to whenever the `data` stats is set by writing that value to the database.
3. This in turn triggers the first effect again, which once again calls `setData`.
4. Which then again triggers the second effect.
5. This repeats endlessly.

To prevent an endless loop, compare the old and new values in either of the effects and skip further processing if they are the same.

Comment: Doesn't the first effect only run on component mount? How does this cause a infinite loop? Also the second effect doesn't change any data locally, I'm only updating the data on the server when it changes locally, basically to keep in sync.

Comment: It should indeed only run on mounting, but I suspect there's a loop somehow. I recommend running in the debugger with some breakpoints or adding some logging to confirm where the loop is coming from.